# Scrapy Crawlspider not crawling is it the RegEx?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to navigate to each county and then each city in each county from here: 
http://www.accountant-finder.com/CA/California-accountants.html

My code opens the main page listed above, scrapes the title per the parser function, but does not seem to apply the rule to follow the county links (relative paths) starting with "/CA/" (like CA/Alameda/Alameda_county-California-accountants.html).

I've tried modifying the rule using various reg-ex's to no avail. What am I missing?

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from acctfinder.items import Accountant
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class AccountantSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Accountant"
    allowed_domains = ["accountant-finder.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.accountant-finder.com/CA/California-accountants.html"]
    rules =(Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('\/CA\/.*',)),callback="parse_item",follow=True),)

    def parse(self,response):
        item = Accountant()
        title = response.xpath('//h1/text()')[0].extract()
        print("title is: "+title)
        item['title'] = title
        return item
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a common mistake when using `CrawlSpider`. Checking the documentation closely it specifies, you [shouldn't be using the `parse` method](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules).

Another thing about your spider, the rule specifies that each item should be processed in the `parse_item` method. so just change the `parse` method to `parse_item` and it should start working.

Comment: Thanks for that it seems to work now - I had read that to mean not using the parse method in the rule.